# Rails: How to reference images in CSS within Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

There's a strange issue with Rails 4 on Heroku.  When images are compiled they have hashes added to them, yet the reference to those files from within CSS don't have the proper name adjusted.  Here's what I mean.  I have a file called logo.png. Yet when it shows up on heroku it is viewed as:

```
/assets/logo-200a00a193ed5e297bb09ddd96afb953.png
```

However the CSS still states:

```
background-image:url("./logo.png");
```

The result: the image doesn't display.  Anybody run into this?  How can this be resolved?

Comment: Just FYI, Heroku has confirmed that it's a bug ... they are working on a solution

Comment: Can you give an update on this? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 409, accepted):

Sprockets together with Sass has [some nifty helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-sass) you can use to get the job done. Sprockets will *only* process these helpers if your stylesheet file extensions are either `.css.scss` or `.css.sass`.

---

**Image specific helper:**

```
background-image: image-url("logo.png")
```

---

**Agnostic helper:**

```
background-image: asset-url("logo.png", image)
background-image: asset-url($asset, $asset-type)
```

---

Or if you want to embed the image data in the css file:

```
background-image: asset-data-url("logo.png")
```

Comment: `asset-data-url` works for me after I changed my .css file to .css.scss file in a Rails 4 app. Thanks!

Comment: @fatman13 Yes, this only works with .scss and .sass files as far as I know.

Comment: Jeff: The others does work providing your asset url options are set up correctly. It doesn't apply for `asset-data-url` since it embeds the whole file inside the stylesheet.

Comment: Similar to @fatman13 since I was using `sass-rails` I finally ended up adding the file extension `.scss` to the offending .css file(s) so they all end in `.css.scss`, then replaced all instances of `url('blah.png')` with `url(asset-path('blah.png'))` (in my case all the blah.pngs were in a `/vendor`ed folder).

Comment: `asset-url($asset)` should be used for sprockets 3, the version with `$asset-type` probably works with some older version

Comment: Benefit to using `image-url` over `asset-url`?

Answer (score 60):

Don't know why, but only thing that worked for me was using **asset_path** *instead* of **image_path**, even though my images are under the **assets/images/** directory:

**Example:**

```
app/assets/images/mypic.png
```

**In Ruby:**

```
asset_path('mypic.png')
```

**In .scss:**

```
url(asset-path('mypic.png'))
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Figured it out- turns out these asset helpers come from the [**sass-rails**](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails) gem (which I had installed in my project).

Comment: works for me, really very good rails way solution. Thanks @Yarin

Comment: Yes! After several hours of banging my head on the wall, your "asset-path" solution finally worked for me on my .css.scss file! `background-image: url(asset-path('off.png'))`

Comment: For those building with Rails 6, you don't need to install the `sass-rails` gem. The helpers work out of the box.

Answer (score 37):

In Rails 4, you can reference an image located in `assets/images/` in your `.SCSS` files easily like this:

```
.some-div {
  background-image: url(image-path('pretty-background-image.jpg'));
}
```

---

When you launch the application in development mode (`localhost:3000`), you should see something like:

```
background-image: url("/assets/pretty-background-image.jpg");
```

In production mode, your assets will have the cache helper numbers:

```
background-image: url("/assets/pretty-background-image-8b313354987c309e3cd76eabdb376c1e.jpg");
```

Comment: @MikeLyons: Just tested it on a brand new Rails 4.1 project and deployed to Heroku and it's working fine for me. You must have touched something on `production.rb`.

Answer (score 25):

The hash is because the asset pipeline and server Optimize caching
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Try something like this:

```
 background-image: url(image_path('check.png'));
```

Goodluck

Comment: In your case what should be the file extension ? Only `.css` didn't work for me.

Comment: Work for me! Thanks bro!

Answer (score 11):

In css

```
background: url("/assets/banner.jpg");
```

although the original path is /assets/images/banner.jpg, by convention you have to add just /assets/ in the url method

Comment: Using plain ol CSS, I thought I was going insane - thank you!

Comment: this will not get compiled in production

Comment: Wow, thank you, that is not very intuitive. So I guess all assets in the asset paths (`vendor/assets`, `app/assets`, `lib/assets`, etc) get combined into a single assets folder after prepossessing is complete?

Comment: This will not working in Production because in Production your assets get compiled with get a MD5 hash affixed to the end of the name and, with typical settings, `/assets/banner.jpg` will not work. Instead it'll be something like `/assets/banner-f719451f1e0ddd15f153c4eedde044b2.jpg`. **TL;DR Don't use this.**

Answer (score 10):

None of the answers says about the way, when I'll have `.css.erb` extension, how to reference *images*. For me worked both in **production** and **development** as well :

[2.3.1 CSS and ERB](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization)

The asset pipeline automatically evaluates **ERB**. This means if you add an erb extension to a **CSS** asset (for example, `application.css.erb`), then helpers like `asset_path` are available in your CSS rules:

```
.class { background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'image.png' %>) }
```

This writes the path to the particular asset being referenced. In this example, it would make sense to have an image in one of the asset load paths, such as `app/assets/images/image.png`, which would be referenced here. If this image is already available in `public/assets` as a fingerprinted file, then that path is referenced.

If you want to use a data URI - a method of embedding the image data directly into the **CSS** file - you can use the `asset_data_uri` helper.

```
.logo { background: url(<%= asset_data_uri 'logo.png' %>) }
```

This inserts a correctly-formatted data URI into the CSS source.

*Note that the closing tag cannot be of the style -%>.*

Answer (score 5):

Only this snippet does not work for me:

```
background-image: url(image_path('transparent_2x2.png'));
```

But rename *stylename.scss* to *stylename.css.scss* helps me.

Answer (score 4):

WHAT I HAVE FOUND AFTER HOURS OF MUCKING WITH THIS:

WORKS :

```
background-image: url(image_path('transparent_2x2.png')); 

// how to add attributes like repeat, center, fixed?
```

The above outputs something like: `"/assets/transparent_2x2-ec47061dbe4fb88d51ae1e7f41a146db.png"`

Notice the **leading "/"**, and **it's within quotes**.
Also note the **scss extension and image_path helper** in yourstylesheet.css.scss.  The image is in the **app/assets/images directory**.

Doesn't work:

```
background: url(image_path('transparent_2x2.png') repeat center center fixed;
```

doesn't work, invalid property:

```
background:url(/assets/pretty_photo/default/sprite.png) 2px 1px repeat center fixed;
```

My last resort was going to be to put these in my public s3 bucket and load from there, but finally got something going.

Comment: For anyone coming here and still having troubles: Ensure that your css file is updated and that you haven't precompiled your assets locally and forgot about updating them.

Comment: Hartwig - what does that mean? Do you mean you have to run precompile again before this method will work? I've tried everything suggested on this post (everything) and nothing is working for me

Answer (score 4):

Interestingly, if I use 'background-image', it does not work:

```
background-image: url('picture.png');
```

But just 'background', it does:

```
background: url('picture.png');
```

Comment: but that only works from the scss file, not when placed in a style property assignment within a div... i'm confuse

Comment: `background: url('picture.png');` Works for Rails 7

Answer (score 4):

Referencing the [Rails documents](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) we see that there are a few ways to link to images from css. Just go to section 2.3.2.

First, make sure your css file has the .scss extension if it's a sass file.

Next, you can use the ruby method, which is really ugly:

```
#logo { background: url(<%= asset_data_uri 'logo.png' %>) }
```

Or you can use the specific form that is nicer:

```
image-url("rails.png") returns url(/assets/rails.png)
image-path("rails.png") returns "/assets/rails.png"
```

Lastly, you can use the general form:

```
asset-url("rails.png") returns url(/assets/rails.png)
asset-path("rails.png") returns "/assets/rails.png"
```

Answer (score 1):

In some cases the following can also be applier

## logo { background: url(<%= asset_data_uri 'logo.png' %>) }

Source: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Answer (score 1):

You can add to your css .erb extension. Ej: style.css.erb

Then you can put:

```
background: url(<%= asset_path 'logo.png' %>) no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 1):

When using gem 'sass-rails', in Rails 5, bootstrap 4, the following worked for me,

in .scss file:

```
    background-image: url(asset_path("black_left_arrow.svg"));
```

in view file(e.g. .html.slim):

```
    style=("background-image: url(#{ show_image_path("event_background.png") })");
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you there every single time.

```
background-image: url(<%= asset_data_uri 'transparent_2x2.png'%>);
```

Answer (score 0):

By default Rails 4 will not serve your assets. To enable this functionality you need to go into config/application.rb and add this line:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline#serve-assets

Comment: This works, but wouldn't this undo the benefits of precompiling the assets?

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 4, simply use

`.hero {
  background-image: url("picture.jpg");
}`

in your style.css file as long as the background image is tucked in app/assets/images.

Comment: Read question full

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```css
background: #4C2516 url('imagename.png') repeat-y 0 0;
```