# Javascript not working - changing image to text on click

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've asked a [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377505/change-2-images-to-one-text-onclick) recently on how to change 2 icons to text on click. The solution worked for a while, but now it's not working. Is there another way to do it or is the problem in the code? I face the problem with other scripts very often.

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_nested_form
//= require_tree .
```

show.html.erb

```
<div class="thumbsup">
<%= link_to image_tag('othericons/thumbsup_off.PNG', height: '20', width: '20', like_post_comment_path(comment.post_id, comment), method: :put, :remote => true %>
</div>

<div class="thumbsdown">
<%= link_to image_tag('othericons/thumbsdown_off.PNG', height: '20', width: '20', dislike_post_comment_path(comment.post_id, comment), method: :put, :remote => true %>
</div>
```

html output

```
<div class="thumbsup">
    <a data-method="put" data-remote="true" href="/posts/1/comments/4/like" rel="nofollow">
        <img alt="Thumbsup off" height="21" src="/assets/othericons/thumbsup_off.PNG" width="20" />
    </a>
</div>

<div class="thumbsdown">
    <a data-method="put" data-remote="true" href="/posts/1/comments/4/dislike" rel="nofollow">
        <img alt="Thumbsdown off" height="21" src="/assets/othericons/thumbsdown_off.PNG" width="20" />
    </a>
</div>
```

icons.js

```
$('.thumbsdown a, .thumbsup a').on('click', function() 
{
    $('.thumbsdown').before('You voted')
    $('.thumbsdown, .thumbsup').remove()
})
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not working?" Are any errors occurring? Are the desired elements found by the selectors? Are the elements likely to be replaced?

Comment: Please show the relevant code directly in this question.

Comment: I updated the post. By not working I mean - when I click on one of the icons, it doesn't change to text.

Comment: Please show the rendered HTML rather than the server-side code.

Answer (score 0):

If it was working before, the problem is likely an issue with [Turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks):

```
$(document).on("click", ".thumbsdown a, .thumbsup a", function() {
    $('.thumbsdown').before('You voted')
    $('.thumbsdown, .thumbsup').remove()
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work properly. It changes images to text on click, but it changes it for all comments on the page at the same time.