# Heroku does not serve background image, localhost does?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I have a problem with my rails application (Rails 4.0.0.rc2, ruby 2.0.0p195).

The behavior is weird: My localhost shows the background picture properly, Heroku doesn't.

In the heroku logs I can see the following error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/piano.jpg"):
```

I have created the background image by inserting the following code in my custom.css.scss:

```
.full { 
  background: image-url("piano.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

And I am triggering this with the following code, which I have on my static page:

```
<body class="full">
....
</body>
```

I already have the gem running in production:

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

In production.rb I have set the following setting to true:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

However, the image is not being shown. Can you help me out?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15257555/how-to-reference-images-in-css-within-rails-4


You may refer to this question.

Comment: Yes. However, the problem is not based on the referencing I chose! It has to do with the precompilation of the assets.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Make sure you set these in your production.rb file

```
config.cache_classes = true
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true
```

Comment: This was my issue. After nearly bashing my head in over the past week I'd like to say thank you!

Comment: Can you explain why did this solution worked? @Brock90

Comment: Note that `config.serve_static_assets` has changed to `config.public_file_server`. Also, thanks for this answer. I just needed `config.assets.compile` even though I precompiled my assets.

Answer (score 12):

I have found the solution for the issue myself:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

After running this command in my console, the picture was shown properly.

Previously I had only tried to run:

```
rake assets:precompile
```

That alone didn't help. You have to address the production environment in your command.

I hope this serves as a reference for other users.

Answer (score 4):

I needed a combination of the other answers to work for me.

I needed to use @Brock90's production config settings as well as precompile the assets as Alex mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

[With the `background` property and SASS](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-sass):

```
background: image-url("my_image.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score -2):

Don't have your pictures in sub-directories within the images/ directory

If anyone is still having trouble with this. I was looking everywhere for a solution and I thought I tried everything. For my case I had instances like

```
background-image: url("containers/filled/Firkin-Keg-5-Gallons_filled.png");
```

So I had folders within images. This worked fine for localhost, but it would not work on heroku.

```
background-image: url("Firkin-Keg-5-Gallons_filled.png");
```

no more sub-directories.

**EDIT**
This is wrong. Refer to comments below for proper usage

Comment: This is dead wrong. Sub-folders work perfectly. You must however use it correctly: `background-image: url(image_path("containers/filled/Firkin-Keg-5-Gallons_filled.png"))` and make sure your stylesheet file has the ending `.scss`

Comment: Use the built in asset pipeline SCSS helpers to link to your pipeline compiled assets. There are a bunch but each one links to the corresponding `/app/assets` path: `image-url`, `font-url`