# File Not Found Error When Changing style.css.scss to style.css.scss.erb

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku, erb

I have been having a [lot of trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37401940/heroku-not-showing-scss-background-images) getting my background images to show up when I deploy my rails app to Heroku.  I finally found this in the Heroku documentation:

> In Rails 4 sprockets will only produce digest filenames. This means
>   that you must use an ERB helper such as this to reference your assets:
>
> ```
> <%= asset_path('logo.png') %>
> ```
>
> Make sure to add a .erb extension to any
>   files in app/assets that use an ERB helper. So application.css would
>   need to be application.css.erb.

I tried renaming the `style.css.scss` file with the offending background images to `style.css.scss.erb`.  This enabled me to change the link to the offending background images to:

```
background: <%= asset_path('bg-hero-000.jpg') %> no-repeat center center fixed;
```

However, I can't tell whether this was the magic bullet that will let Heroku actually display my images because I am now getting a `File to import not found or unreadable:` error for that file.

I did some pretty extensive googling on this issue but can't seem to find a way out of the error.  Any help or wisdom would be awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had this issue in the past and could only solve it by putting my image file in the public folder.

Comment: I tried linking it to the version in my public folder, but had the same problem where the image simply doesn't appear.

Comment: What does your css render as?