# Image urls for Rails 4 + Less not including the hash

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, less

I have a Rails 4 application and am using the `less-rails` gem. In `main.css.less`, I add a background image to the site using:

```
body {
  background-image: image-url("background.jpg");
}
```

Everything works fine locally, but when I push up to my server with precompiled assets, the image url is not updating to include the hash. That is, the image now lives at `public/assets/background-074c0b767cd8cfb2da93b37ea3596326.jpg` but my css file still says `url(/assets/background.jpg)`.

The link below seemed very promising, but none of the recommended solutions have worked (most of them are specific to `sass`, although I did try `image-url`, `asset-url` and their respective `-path`'s).

[How to reference images in CSS within Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15257555/how-to-reference-images-in-css-within-rails-4)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The "hash" is known as [asset fingerprinting](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html), and is a standard feature of the Rails `asset pipeline`, which means it should work if everything is done right :)

We've had experience of this before, and you're 90% of the way there with it

I'd recommend 2 fixes:

---

**1. Use `asset_url` in your LESS:**

```
body {
  background-image: asset_url("background.jpg");
}
```

---

**2. [Precompile your assets](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets)**

```
#config/environments/production.rb
config.serve_static_assets = true

#cmd
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

This should make your assets static, thus allowing your CSS to load them with no issues!