# Rails 4 + DreamHost FastCGI: Precompiling assets won't change image-url links

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, fastcgi, dreamhost

I'm running a Rails 4 app on a DreamHost shared server using FastCGI, and I can't seem to get assets working properly.

Precompile will work to compile application.css.scss, but `image-url` and `asset-url` links do not changes to the correct values (ex. `url(/assets/images/image-{digest}.png`).

I've heard that you can change it to .css.scss.erb and use <%= image_tag "image.png" %>, but I'd rather not change every single link in the file if I can help it.

Am I missing something? I'm running

`bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` and I have in `production.rb`

```
config.assets.compile = false
config.assets.digest = true
```

What haven't I done yet?

Answer (score 0):

It was just a matter of setting

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

in `production.rb`, and rerunning

`bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`

Found at: [Image urls for Rails 4 + Less not including the hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441422/image-urls-for-rails-4-less-not-including-the-hash)

Answer (score 0):

I got this warning message in rails-4.2.2: "DEPRECATION WARNING: The configuration option `config.serve_static_assets` has been renamed to `config.serve_static_files` to clarify its role (it merely enables serving everything in the `public` folder and is unrelated to the asset pipeline). The `serve_static_assets` alias will be removed in Rails 5.0. Please migrate your configuration files accordingly."

This was the line created by default with my app. You should use static_files instead.

```
config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
```

I found [Rails 4: assets not loading in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18700219/rails-4-assets-not-loading-in-production#18702000) and added `config.assets.precompile =  ['*.js', '*.css', '*.css.erb']` so you should be able to have something like

```
config.assets.precompile =  ['*.png', '*.js', '*.css', '*.css.erb']
```

Just add the file type to the array