# background image heroku rails not working

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have the background image for a basic rails site I made working fine but when I pushed it up to heroku it gave me the following error

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://young-oasis-2855.herokuapp.com/assets/joy.jpg
```

here is the code from my css file

```
body {
  background: url(/assets/joy.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

I have several other pics uploaded and working fine anyone know why this is not working on heroku, but is still working locally?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reference images in CSS within Rails 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15257555/how-to-reference-images-in-css-within-rails-4)

Answer (score 2):

try using `image-url('joy.jpg')` instead of url

This answer may give more info for you:
[How to reference images in CSS within Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15257555/how-to-reference-images-in-css-within-rails-4)

Comment: do you know why using image-url makes this work on heroku, when it works fine locally?

Comment: Because locally, you aren't using the asset pipeline. You'll need to look into how the asset pipeline works if you'd like a deeper understanding. Note: this problem would occur on any server that you deploy to - once it goes into production mode.

Answer (score 0):

Similarly, I've used a CSS property like this.

```
background-image:url('joy.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also got this error, I have solved it by:

Production.rb

```
config.cache_classes = true
config.assets.compile = true
```

background-image: url(assets/hero_bg_2.jpg)