# 'x' for deselecting items in jquery chosen does not appear

Tags: jquery, icons, jquery-chosen

New to chosen I have come across a strange thing.
Having a  with multiple option selects.
I have applied chosen to the list like this

```
$("#valgteSteder").chosen({
    no_results_text: "No results",
    placeholder_text_single: "-- choose --",
    disable_search: false
});
```

when I select one or more options I don't get the 'X' to right in the displayed item for deselect. I have tried to search for a solution to in the chosen doc's but to no avail. Any Idea of what I'm doing wrong or missing?

Comment: check `chosen.css` `search-choice-close` class and you should have this image `chosen-sprite.png` and it should be in correct path

Comment: Thanks Sridhar - You set me off in the right direction. :-) Problem was that the .png was not in the same folder as the CSS. Thanks - it works alright now

Comment: i will add it as answer accept it

Answer (score 9):

Try this

Check `chosen.css` `search-choice-close` class and you should have this image `chosen-sprite.png` and it should be in correct path (folder)

Answer (score 2):

For me, everything was working in development, but the icons were not being found after I deployed my rails app to Heroku (odd).  I changed all the `url("chosen-sprite.png")` references in my chosen.scss to `image_url("chosen-sprite.png")` and now all icons are being resolved properly.

Comment: Sounds like you had this issue, which is specific to Rails: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15257555/how-to-reference-images-in-css-within-rails-4

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of Chosen have two images. Check that you have ***both*** of the following images in the correct location (by default, same file path as the chosen.css file):

1. chosen-sprite.png
2. chosen-sprite@2x.png

I had the first image but was missing the second.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, however it wasn't a CSS problem.  It turns out that the small 'x' to deselect only appears when you tell chosen to do that via an option:

```
$('.myelement').chosen({allow_single_deselect: true});
```

[Full list of options](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html)