# Rails 4.1.4: CSS background image not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

This is the CSS in my page.css.scss

```
#test {
  background-image: image-url("bigstock.jpg")
}
```

This is my routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get ':controller(/:action(/:id))'
  root 'page#index'
```

When I visit `localhost:3000` I see the texts but no image.
When I try to navigate to the address in the CSS, `http://localhost:3000/assets/bigstock.jpg`, I get the error message:

```
No route matches [GET] "/assets/bigstock-blured-lighhts-from-peak-Victo-63827467.jpg"
```

I am new to rails and have tried many different methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15257555/how-to-reference-images-in-css-within-rails-4) like using `asset-url`, `background`, `image_path` but nothing works.

I couldn't do try setting `config.serve_static_assets = true` though as it throws some errors.

Since this is a fresh install, it shouldn't be too difficult to do something so simple? I guess I might be heading in the wrong direction.

**Update**:
I have just tried `config.serve_static_assets = true`. Didn't help. Added it in the wrong place intially.

Comment: What were the errors with `serve_static_assets` turned on?

Comment: `undefined local variable or method 'config' for main:Object` when I start the server. Read that its for older version of Rails, but I'm not sure.

Comment: The error message is saying that the file name is `bigstock-blured-lighhts-from-peak-Victo-63827467.jpg`.Is your file is `bigstock.jpg` or `bigstock-blured-lighhts-from-peak-Victo-63827467.jpg`?

Comment: Hm..interesting I wanted to try renaming the filename to `bigstock` but probably changed a wrong location. I just tried renaming the file in `/asset/images/` and it worked. So long filenames is the problem?

Comment: What is the original name of your file before you renamed?

Comment: from `bigstock-blured-lighhts-from-peak-Victo-63827467.jpg` to `bigstock.jpg`. shall try adding some hypens later and see if it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

The filename was the problem here. Removing the last hypen and numbers worked. I also realized that the image doesn't load if the filename ends with hypen, followed by a string of numbers with length greater than 6.