# Referencing images in css for rails prod

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I changed my css files to do the following:

changed my_css.css.scss to my_css.css.scss.erb:

```
#mainLogo {
    background: url('<%= image_path 'sprites.png'%>') no-repeat;
}
```

but it resolves to:

```
background: url("/assets/sprites.png") no-repeat;
```

If I place the same code on my home page (application.html.slim):

```
p=image_path 'sprites.png'
```

it prints out:

```
/assets/sprites-eab0989be1d5f5ba1c08c46728c2416b.png
```

Which is what I want.

How do I get the css file to have the fingerprinted version as well?

**What I've tried? Just about everything, but here is a few things:**

```
background-image: image-url("sprites.png");
```

turns into:

```
background-image: url(/assets/sprites.png);
```

(no fingerprint / digested filename)

Adding `//= depend_on_asset 'sprites.png'`  to the css file doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Please see this [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15591726/85125) post.

Comment: @BartJedrocha It resolves the same.

Comment: @BartJedrocha I was finally able to get something to work with 
background-image: asset-data-url('sprites.png'); but why?