# Changing button image in CSS in Rails/Spree store

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm creating a Spree store, and trying to make a button use an image instead of the default button that is included with the extension (and bootstrap). I can target the proper button in CSS, and deactivate the background color, border, etc. The background url doesn't work for the image (path: "app/assets/images/heart-icon.png"), but it works fine for any external image url.

I assume my problem lies within the asset pipeline, but I can't figure out the proper path to set as the url.

From my .css file:

```
form.new_wished_product button.btn.btn-info {
  background: url(assets/heart-icon.png);
  background-color: transparent;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: transparent;
  border: none;
}
```

The button doesn't need to change when hovered or clicked -- it's just a simple image.

Thanks!

EDIT:

I saw the related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15257555/how-to-reference-images-in-css-within-rails-4) but thought mine was different because I had tried those solutions. I was trying to do this with plain CSS and changing the file extension to .css.scss worked for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reference images in CSS within Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15257555/how-to-reference-images-in-css-within-rails-4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the `image-url()` [helper](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-sass) instead of `url()`?

`image-url('heart-icon.png');`

This will find the asset within your site's file structure.

> When using the asset pipeline, paths to assets must be re-written and sass-rails provides `-url` and `-path` helpers (hyphenated in Sass, underscored in Ruby) for the following asset classes: image, font, video, audio, JavaScript and stylesheet.

Comment: I have tried that, and it didn't work. I think because mine is a CSS file, not Sass?

Comment: I created a new file, button.css.scss, and moved my code into that file, which worked as expected.

Comment: Yeah, Sass would be the requirement. That was not clear from the original question unfortunately.