# Heroku can't load image from assets

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I have an image in the `assets/images` and I want to set it as a background on the main page refers to a given class, but I do not see `image` in production Heroku

application.scss

```
.has-bg-img { background: url('img.PNG'); center center; background-size:cover; }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my Rails app, I change the filename to end with `.scss.erb` and then have the following as an example. A comment at the top, followed by the example.

```
//= depend_on_asset "sprite-article-r4.svg"
.contents {
  background-image:url('<%= asset_path("sprite-article-r5.svg") %>');
}
```

Reference this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15257555/how-to-reference-images-in-css-within-rails-4)

Answer (score 0):

you must set a full path like `url('localhost/apps/assets/images/myimg.jpg`')

Comment: bot how is it in production?

Answer (score 0):

If your assets are not static and committed into your repo, and you're trying to reference a dynamically uploaded image, you might have to read on how to work around with [Heroku's ephemeral filesystem](https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted)

Answer (score 0):

You can try `image-url` or `asset-url` helpers.
[Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-sass)

Edit :
actually, i'm not sure about your syntax

```
.has-bg-img {
  background-image: url('img.PNG');
  background-position: center center;
  background-size:cover;
}
```

it should work better.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails, you have to prepend directory name to url. For your case change

```
.has-bg-img { background: url('img.PNG'); center center; background-size:cover; }
```

to

```
.has-bg-img { background: image-url('img.PNG'); center center; background-size:cover; }
```

This is because you are storing your image in images(assets/images) directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try to the following

```
.has-bg-img { 
    background-image: asset-url('img.png'); 
    background-size: cover; 
}
```

This should work, I don't why you use `center center;` I think that is syntactically invalid see this [`Horizontal & Vertical Align`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp)